# Target number sum finder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is a Target number solution finder which I made with tkinter and is where the user enters a number they want and enters 4 other numbers to find the sum to make the number they want.

This is a screenshot on what the GUI looks like:
[image]

This is the code for the project:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, IntVar, Entry, Text, W, N, WORD, INSERT
from itertools import permutations,combinations_with_replacement



class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets() 


    def create_widgets(self):

        self.target_num = IntVar()
        self.num1 = IntVar()
        self.num2 = IntVar()
        self.num3 = IntVar()
        self.num4 = IntVar()       
        # self.title("target number solution")

        Label(self,image='', bg="white").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(self, text="Enter target number:", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry1 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.target_num, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter first number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry2 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num1, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry2.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter second number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num2, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry3.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter third number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry3 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num3, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry3.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=N)


        Label(self, text="Enter fourth number:",bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.textentry4 = Entry(self, textvariable=self.num4, width=20, bg="white")
        self.textentry4.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=N)


        Button(self, text="Solve", width=6, command=self.solver).grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.output = Text(self, width=60, height=10, wrap=WORD, background="white")
        self.output.grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=N)

    def solver(self):
        self.output.delete(1.0, INSERT)
        target = self.target_num.get()
        number1 = self.num1.get()
        number2 = self.num2.get()
        number3 = self.num3.get()
        number4 = self.num4.get()
        numbers = [number1, number2, number3, number4]
        operators = ["+","-","*","/"]
        groups    = ['X+X+X+X', 'X+X+(X+X)', 'X+(X+X)+X', '(X+X+X)+X', '(X+X)+X+X', 'X+(X+X+X)', '((X+X)+X)+X', 'X+(X+(X+X))', 'X+((X+X)+X)', '(X+X)+(X+X)', '(X+(X+X))+X']
        seen = set()
        for values in permutations(numbers,len(numbers)):
            for operCombo in combinations_with_replacement(operators,len(numbers)-1):
                for oper in permutations(operCombo,len(numbers)-1):
                    formulaKey = "".join(str(oper+values))
                    if formulaKey in seen: continue # ignore variations on parentheses alone
                    for pattern in groups:
                        formula = "".join(str(o)+str(p) for o,p in zip([""]+list(oper), pattern.split("+")))
                        formula = "".join(str(v)+str(p) for v,p in zip([""]+list(values),formula.split("X")))
                        try:
                            if eval(formula) == target:
                                Answer = formula,"=",target
                                seen.add(formulaKey)
                                #insert value in output Textbox
                                self.output.insert(INSERT, Answer) 
                                self.output.insert(INSERT, '\n') 
                                break
                            elif eval(formula) != target:
                                self.output.insert(INSERT, 'Solution could not be found')
                                break
                        except: pass

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("target number solution")
app.mainloop()
```

I just want suggestions on how I can improve this project to make it better.

All suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am concentrating on the solver method, since my sense for a good UX is close to null. I added inline comments for my changes.

But here some major changes:

- Your code was not showing all combinations because you were breaking the loop after first item.
- The two nested fors with combinations_with_replacement and permutations, does the same as [product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).
- Defined groups and operators as constants (in uppercase) at the beginning of the code.
- Used END instead of INSERT in output so it clears text of previous results.
- Added formula_key right away and not in the condition, it was computing the same formula multiple times.
- [Snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for naming variables convention in python.

Here the code (create_widgets and the constructor stay the same):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, IntVar, Entry, Text, W, N, WORD, INSERT, END
from itertools import permutations, product

# Define constants
OPERATORS = ["+","-","*","/"]
GROUPS    = ['X+X+X+X', 'X+X+(X+X)', 'X+(X+X)+X', '(X+X+X)+X', '(X+X)+X+X', 'X+(X+X+X)', '((X+X)+X)+X', 'X+(X+(X+X))', 'X+((X+X)+X)', '(X+X)+(X+X)', '(X+(X+X))+X']

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # ...

    def create_widgets(self):
        # ...

    def solver(self):
        self.output.delete(1.0, END)  # END removes previous results instead of INSERT
        target = self.target_num.get()
        number1 = self.num1.get()
        number2 = self.num2.get()
        number3 = self.num3.get()
        number4 = self.num4.get()
        numbers = [number1, number2, number3, number4]
        seen = set()
        len_opr = len(numbers) - 1  # Compute once
        for values in permutations(numbers): # No need to specify len
            for oper in product(OPERATORS, repeat=len_opr):  # Product does what you want instead of two fors
                formula_key = "".join(str(oper + values))
                if formula_key in seen: continue # ignore variations for repeated numbers
                seen.add(formula_key)  # Add right away not in the condition
                # if only one operation, do not permute parenthesis
                filtered_groups = [GROUPS[0]] if len(set(oper)) == 1 else GROUPS
                for pattern in filtered_groups:
                    formula = "".join(str(o)+str(p) for o, p in zip([""] + list(oper), pattern.split("+")))
                    formula = "".join(str(v)+str(p) for v, p in zip([""] + list(values), formula.split("X")))
                    try:
                        if eval(formula) == target:
                            answer = formula, "=", target  # vars start by minuscule
                            #insert value in output Textbox
                            self.output.insert(INSERT, answer)
                            self.output.insert(INSERT, '\n')
                            result = True
                        # REMOVE this condition or it does not try all groups with parenthesis
                    except: pass
        if self.output.get("1.0", END)=="\n":
            self.output.insert(INSERT, 'Solution could not be found')
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("target number solution")
app.mainloop()
```

If you have any questions, don't hesitate!

Comment: I am getting this error:     `self.output.delete(1.0, END) 
NameError: name 'END' is not defined`

Comment: Check the first line, it has to be imported

Comment: Thanks the error is gone but now I get another error:`for oper in product(OPERATORS, repeat=len_opr):`
`NameError: name 'product' is not defined`

Comment: Check the second line, it has to be imported ;)

Comment: I have another question, is is possible to remove duplicate solutions?

Comment: There are duplicates? For which case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94244/discussion-between-palvarez-and-system123456).

Answer (score 2):

is it working now and i have an evil hack in there:

- Same values inside a loop
- You do have only 5 groups
- Division by 0 must be escaped
- Not building a string and then eval, just have list of functions, that makes code smaller and runs faster
- No hashing need because results do not repeat unless you do many times the same digits combo...
- Attention, evil hack: Generate combination of functions by increasing some digit 
  and viewing its bits : 12, 34, 56 as digits from 0-3 what are function indexes.

There it is:

```
                    fa = self.ops [op_bits & 3]
                fb = self.ops [(op_bits & 12) >> 2 ]
                fc = self.ops [(op_bits & 48) >> 4 ]
```

enjoy the crap:

```
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, IntVar, Entry, Text, W, N, WORD, INSERT


class Application(Frame):

    #extract constant fields:

    op_str = ['+', '-' , '*' , '/']

    ops = [lambda a,b : a+b if (a is not None and b is not None) else None,
                    lambda a,b : a-b if (a is not None and b is not None) else None, 
                    lambda a,b : a*b if (a is not None and b is not None) else None,
                    lambda a,b :  a/b if (b != 0 and a is not None and b is not None) else None, 
                   ]

    max_combinations = 1 << 6

    group_strs    = ['((%d%s%d)%s%d)%s%d', '%d%s(%d%s(%d%s%d))', '%d%s((%d%s%d)%s%d)', '(%d%s%d)%s(%d%s%d)', '(%d%s(%d%s%d))%s%d']

        #clumsy a lil bit
    groups = [lambda a,b,c,d,fa,fb,fc :  fc(fb(fa(a,b),c),d),
              lambda a,b,c,d,fa,fb,fc :  fa(a,fb(b,fc(c,d))),
            lambda a,b,c,d,fa,fb,fc :  fa(a,fc(fb(b,c),d)),
            lambda a,b,c,d,fa,fb,fc :  fb(fa(a,b), fc(c,d)),
            lambda a,b,c,d,fa,fb,fc :  fc(fa(a,fb(b,c)),d),


                          ]    


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets() 







    def create_widgets(self):

        self.entries = []  
        self.vars = [IntVar() for _ in range (5)]
        self.texts = ['Enter target number' , 
                      'Enter first number', 
                      'Enter second number', 
                      'Enter third number', 
                      'Enter fourth number']


        for index, var in enumerate(self.vars):
            Label(self, text=self.texts[index], bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold").grid(row=2*index, column=0, sticky=N)
            e = Entry(self, textvariable= self.vars[index] , width=20, bg="white")
            e.grid(row=2*index+1, column=0, sticky=N)
            self.entries.append(e)

        Button(self, text="Solve", width=6, command=self.solver).grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=N)
        self.output = Text(self, width=60, height=10, wrap=WORD, background="white")
        self.output.grid(row=13, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=N)   

    def solver(self):
        self.output.delete(1.0, INSERT)
        target = self.vars[0].get()
        numbers = [e.get() for e in self.vars[1:]]


        count = 0
        for gr_num, group in enumerate(self.groups):


            for op_bits in range(0,self.max_combinations):
                count += 1
                #evil hacks here
                fa = self.ops [op_bits & 3]
                fb = self.ops [(op_bits & 12) >> 2 ]
                fc = self.ops [(op_bits & 48) >> 4 ]
            # or even shorter like
            # fs = [(op_bits & (3 << x)) >> x for x in range(0,self.max_combinations) ]

                my_eval = group(*numbers, fa,fb,fc)
                print('my_eval' , my_eval, ' =' , *numbers, fa,fb,fc,  )
                if my_eval == target:
                    formula = self.group_strs[gr_num] % (numbers[0],self.op_str[op_bits & 3],numbers[1],self.op_str[(op_bits & 12) >> 2],numbers[2],self.op_str[(op_bits & 48) >> 4],numbers[3])
                    Answer = formula,"=",target , ' found in ' , count , 'iterations'
                    #seen.add(formulaKey)
                    #insert value in output Textbox
                    self.output.insert(INSERT, Answer) 
                    self.output.insert(INSERT, '\n')
                    return

        self.output.insert(INSERT, 'Solution could not be found in ' + str(count) +  ' iterations')






root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title("target number solution")
app.mainloop()
```